# request.params.merge and filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have the following problem. I am new to Rails and I want to filter posts based on provided list of categories. Currently I add categories and show them on the main page. They account for links to their specific category page, then I add a link:

```
<%= link_to category.name, request.params.merge(category: category.id) %>
```

In effect I get the following link e.g.: /profile/2?categories=7

User can submit posts to individual categories and they should be shown on the main page through such code

```
<% @category.posts.each do |post| %>
   <%= render "post_large", post: post %>
<% end %>
```

as far as it works on each categories page e.g. categories/7, it does not render posts on the main page. My current controller is:

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
    
      def index
      end
    
      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @category = Category.new
      
    end
    
    end
```

Best,

Comment: Do you want to render all posts? What controller and what action main page does use?

Comment: Controller action could help us understand the question more. 
I believe you want to show only Posts from specific Category on "Main Page" if category is on GET params, eg. /mainpage/?category=7 . So on controller you can do something like `@category = params[:category] ? Category.where(id: params[:category]) : Category.all`

Comment: thanks, read below...

Comment: well, did not pain attention to code, as description was saying you want to filter posts from categories, the code up there should be used to retrieve all categories or specific category if you have category in GET parameters -> so us it where you fetches those categories.
btw you will never see list of post from that code: `@category.posts.each ...` as the @category will always be a `new_record` and therefore the posts relation will be empty once page rendered

Comment: Do you mean that @category.posts.each will not be able to fetch category id from params e.g.  /profile/2?categories=7. I thought it works that way. I get sth into params and I can source that information into the main pages objects...

Comment: You should take some basic course of Ruby on Rails to get know how it works in general :) 
Like I've pointed out if you assign in controller `@category = Category.new` then in view the `@category.posts` will be empty (assuming you do nothing more, e.g. using in Category after initialize callback to fill that posts, etc).
So if you are saying you have posts on that page then it means you are fetching them somewhere else :)